# rails 3, can I create a route that includes a url param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

we have

```
match '/m/:id' => 'foo#mobilemethod'
```

mobilemethod accepts a url param `?find=true` that puts it in 'find mode'

is there a way to add a route `/f/:id` that will call mobilemethod with the url param `?find=true`

(or, is there a way for a method to know WHICH route was originally invoked, in which case I could simply map both /m and /f to the same method then inside the method check which one was invoked on the url)

I tried

```
match '/f/:id' => 'foo#mobilemethod?find=true'
```

and

```
match '/f/:id' => 'foo#mobilemethod/:id?find=true'
```

but get 'unknown action' errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do this trick:

```
match '/f/:id' => 'foo#mobilemethod', :defaults => {:find => true}
```

Comment: perfect , I thought rails would have some cool, simple way to do that!

Answer (score 2):

```
match '/f/:id' => 'foo#mobilemethod'
                    ^       ^
             controller    action


match '/f/:id/find/:find' => 'foo#mobile_method'
```

presents the params id and finding

or do you want a default value?

```
match '/m/:id' => 'foo#mobilemethod', :defaults => { :find => true }
```